# Hide Alarm icon in the status bar

Tags: notifications, 2.3-gingerbread, 2.2-froyo, notification-icons, alarm

I have at least one alarm set to go off daily so the "alarm clock" icon on my notification bar is really pointless.

Is there a way to make this icon hidden in Android Froyo or Android Gingerbread?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, for the same reasons detailed in this answer.

[Can I hide a program from ongoing activities in the notification bar?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1607/hiding-program-from-ongoing-activities-in-the-notification-bar/1612#1612)

Comment: That is not entirely true though, some apps allow to hide the notification. It is an app by app basis.

Comment: True enough, although I was speaking to the stock alarm clock.

Comment: Ah, yup I would agree with what you have then.

Comment: Is there any way to do it at a lower level with rooted access? Maybe replace the current stock clock/alarm app with a modified "stock" clock/alarm app?

Comment: This is not accurate, [removing the icon is possible with the System UI Tuner](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/140486/118870) that comes bundled with recent versions of Android. @SAGExSDX, I think you should consider changing the accepted answer, so that people aren't misled with by this incorrect answer.

Answer (score 11):

On Android Marshmallow, you can use the hidden System UI Tuner.

Open the quick-setting panel, then press and hold the Settings' cog wheel until it starts spinning. You then get an additional settings entry in **System** > **System UI Tuner** > **Status bar**, where you can hide the alarm.

Comment: I see this menu but nothing related to showing the alarm clock icon. Only the ability to set the brightness slider or change the quick menu settings.

Comment: I must add I'm actually on CM13, so it may be different than stock MM.

Comment: After this go to System > System UI Tuner > Status bar, and then find alarm, it was at the bottom on my phone.

Comment: This works in Android 7 (Nougat) too.

Answer (score 3):

Easiest way *if rooted*:
You can use GravityBox, to hide the Alarm-Clock-Symbol.

1. Open the app.
2. Go to "Adapt Status Bar" (I don't know the exact English translation)
3. Choose "Adapt Clock"
4. Tick the box next to "Hide Alarm Symbol"

Comment: Thanks. This is a great answer if I had stuck with the stock alarm clock. Been using Gentle Alarm for years since this question :)

Answer (score 1):

There is if you use the alarm app, Gentle Alarm. Besides the plethora of amazing features that app has, you can also turn off the notification bar icon and the app still runs in the background just fine. I've been running it that way for a long time.

On a semi-related note, my favorite feature of Gentle Alarm is the ability to keep alarms scheduled, but skip as many of them in order as you want. That way if you are on vacation for one day you can turn off scheduled alarm(s) for just that day and not be annoyingly woken up. I was on vacation for a week and was able to turn them all off and the following week I didn't have to remember to turn my alarms back on, already taken care of.

Comment: Those sounds like some great features. I was hoping that there was a way to still use the stock alarm app AND hide the icon. but based on Al E's answer, it doesn't sound like you can. Getting an alternate alarm app was going to be a "if it annoys me enough" last-effort solution.

Comment: Well I would recommend getting the app for not only the annoyance factor, but also all the other features too.

Answer (score 0):

In Gentle Alarm, you must go to the Settings and turn on Advanced Features. Then Other Preferences > Notifications, and then you are presented with many options for the type of notification or turning it off.

Answer (score 0):

You can download Wanam Xposed from Xposed repository [here](https://repo.xposed.info/module/ma.wanam.xposed).

When you open the app you'll be instructed to install the framework (I've done it personally and haven't had any problems).

Once this is done go back to the original app and there will be many customizable features available including one for hiding the alarm clock icon.

This is not my app. I just use it personally on a  stock JB 4.3 (rooted) and find it great.

Answer (score 0):

I achieve this with the app; [Smart Alarm Free](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.tanyu.SmartAlarmFree). It simply has a setting for it. Also it's a way better alarm app.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is, but you need an app for it.

I was surprised to read that this was something people wanted, and so I ended up writing such an app (disclaimer: I wrote the app, but it is free).

It is small and lightweight, and removes the icon, but will also flash the icon every time another app updates the alarm.

If this is something that you would find useful, you can get it for free on the Google Play store:

- [X89 Status Ninja](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobiric.dark.stealthalarm)

Answer (score 0):

Just found this in Marshmallow for anyone coming across this question. Go to Settings > Status Bar > Status Bar Icons and from there you can uncheck the alarm icon.

Comment: Stock Marshmallow, or a custom ROM? I've only seen CyanogenMod having this option.

Comment: Actually it is CM13, but I guess I just assumed it was a stock Marshmallow option.

Answer (score 0):

Provided your Android is rooted and a compatible Xposed Framework<sup><sup>1</sup></sup> is installed, you can use GravityBox xposed module to hide the alarm icon.

I tested with [GravityBox [N]](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.ceco.nougat.gravitybox) and in it, go to *Statusbar tweaks → Clock Settings* → tick *Hide Alarm icon*.

Note that I cannot assure whether earlier Android version specific versions of GravityBox offered this tweak.

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: IMG:]

<sup><sup>1</sup></sup> <sub>Xposed Framework *for stock Android [based] ROMs*: [Android 4.x](http://repo.xposed.info/module/de.robv.android.xposed.installer), [Android 5.x, 6.x and 7.x](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3034811)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

For Oreo, I used [SystemUI Tuner](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zacharee1.systemuituner&hl=en_US). Need to enable the [developer options](https://www.theandroidsoul.com/enable-developer-options-android-o-8-0/) temporarily and grant it necessary rights though a computer. It exposes the necessary system settings and has few other useful settings too.

Bit more detail:
In earlier versions it was possible to invoke the "System UI Tuner" on android system by long pressing settings cog wheel after swiping down on the notification bar to expand it. Sadly it has been decided not to expose this to users on Oreo. So we need a 3rd party app (e.g. first link above). And give that app necessary permissions using developer mode. The two links give all the details and steps.

Answer (score -1):

if you are running Jelly Bean (or newer), there is the option of disabling all notifications from an app. The setting is per-app and can be found in Settings > Apps > (select the app) > uncheck the "Show notifications" box. The one caveat to this method is that the app will no longer show any notifications in the notification bar, but if that's acceptable to you than I've found this method to be an easy way to stop my notification drawer from filling up with unnecessary notifications.

Comment: The questioner isn't talking about a notification. He's talking about the alarm clock icon that shows up on the right-hand end of the notification bar, with the Wi-Fi and battery indicators. Notifications are at the left-hand end of the notification bar.

Answer (score -1):

Also, if you disable notifications entirely for an alarm clock, nothing will pop up when the alarm goes off. To turn off a ringing alarm, you will have to start your alarm clock app from the home screen, find the alarm schedule that is currently ringing, and turn off the scheduled alarm.  You will have no option to snooze the alarm, or silence it but leave it on repeat.  You'd have to turn it off and then on again.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand what you are saying. Could you please try to rephrase your answer. Especially your first sentence is hard to understand.